# List and open Google Docs from a folder using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to retrieve a list of documents from a folder named "myfolder" in Google Docs using Zend Framework.

```
$service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient("my@gmail.com", "password", $service);
$docs = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);
$feed = $docs->getDocumentListFeed('https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/-/myfolder');
$this->view->feed = "";

foreach ($feed as $document) {
    $link = $document->getLink();
    $this->view->feed .= '<a href="'.$link[0]->getHref().'" target="_blank">'.$document->getTitle().'</a><br/>';
}
```

I was able to get a list of all files in "myfolder"; but when I try to open them, I get an error:

> Authorization required
>
> Error 401

I've tried using

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full
```

instead of

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/-/myfolder
```

and I'm able to see all my files. I can open those that are saved under the "Home" directory without any problem. The Error 401 only happens when I try to open files that are saved in a folder.

Why? Any idea?

Comment: I'm answering my own questions... 

I should have used 
`$link[1]->getHref()` instead of `$link[0]->getHref()` because the file is one level away from the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have used $link[1]->getHref() instead of $link[0]->getHref().